# Amazon S3 : The application is giving access denied exception in linux. Why?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3

**I have a spring-boot application to upload and delete a file in Amazon-S3 bucket.**

**The project is working fine on Windows** but when I am trying to upload anything using `curl` command in linux through putty, it's giving me the access denied exception.

*The exception given is :*

`com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied`

*The screenshot :*

[image]

Comment: looks like its not able to read aws creds in linux environment

Comment: yes, when I am running the project it's not able to detect the aws credentials provided in the jar already..

Comment: show code , how you are reading cred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't setup your AWS credentials for your Linux.

The instructions are [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html)

just make sure your have your `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your using IAM credential and S3 policy setting ?

1. Credential

Regardless of platforms, it's necessary to use credentials ([access key id & secret access key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html)). Please check credential files have same access key id.

2. S3 policy

S3 policy can handle deny/allow access according to credentials or IP addresses. Do you configure such policy ?

Comment: I have configured access key id and secret access id in application.yml file and access those things in the my spring boot application using  @Value("${propertiesname.accessKey}") and @Value("${propertiesname.secretKey}")

Comment: @AnishB I recommend you to add debug logging (for cred) before calling S3.